# Program my Logitech M545 Mouse for Mac

Tags: macos, mouse

I am currently using Logitech M545 Mouse, which has two side buttons for convenient operations under Windows.

In windows, one button is for displaying the desktop, and the other is for Start button. I find it really convenient. Logitech claims that one may program the uses of the two buttons for personal use.

Now, I am using it together with my MBPR late 2013, and the two buttons do not work any more. Is it possible to program it so that one button is still for displaying the desktop, and the other open the Application Center?

Answer (score 1):

Mac-compatible Logitech mouses come with a preference pane to program their features.  Or (even if not Mac-compatible) try a third-party mouse-button utility, like [SteerMouse](http://www.plentycom.jp/en/index.html), $20.

**edit**
[Here](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/MAC-OS-driver-support-for-M325-mice/m-p/845922#M40641) is the post about using the Logitech M325 on Mac.  Maybe that will work in other cases, too.

Comment: Unluckily, the SteerMouse is unable to detect the presence of my mouse, saying "Configurable Mouse is Not Found".

Comment: SteerMouse worked with my M325 ... the Logitech web site does not list M545 at all...

Comment: Not listed? Not really... http://www.logitech.com/assets/47506/wireless-mouse-m545-setup-guide.pdf

Comment: Interesting.  If you say you are in the US, then M545 is not listed.

Comment: Is there any alternative to SteerMouse? I think this answer really points to a right direction. It's just that particular software cannot detect my mouse

Comment: Another point: you have to REMOVE the Logitech driver before SteerMouse can detect the mouse.  editing...

Comment: What about USB Overdrive?

Comment: @Max: why not make that a separate answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot! An update from me: it turns out that the SteerMouse that I was previously using is too old. I reinstalled 4.1.3 version. Now it can detect my mouse. The only issue that remains is that it cannot detect the two side buttons on the mouse. All the other buttons are ok and configurable. Any idea? Thanks a lot! Close to the destination!

Comment: Try [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com). It doesn't appear to directly support driver editing for the M545, but it should be able to configure up to 5 buttons on any mouse. The trial version of ControllerMate should be good enough; it can set up to 10 output blocks.

Comment: @GEdgar No time to write a good answer.

Comment: @MaxRied  I would greatly appreciate it if you can help write one. Danke shoen!

Comment: @0942v8653  Good suggestion, I tried it, but it seems not to be able to configure the other brands?

Comment: Please kindly help further solve this. I would greatly appreciate your help! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118466/configure-and-personalise-external-keyboard-buttons-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

It can be worked around by using [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/). The left and right tilt are mouse button 4 & 5 respectively, and the first side button is a command key. So just re-map these button to whatever you want.

For example, if I want the first side button to show desktop, I just need to map it to F11. Also, if I want to map the left and right tilt to scroll horizontally, I just map them to horizontal scroll wheel with repeaters attached. My setting is show below.

Note that ControllerMate is free to use if the number of settings you defined is less then 10. So in my case its totally free.

[image: ControllerMate Building Blocks]