# Configure and personalise external keyboard buttons on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Ok, in fact what I am trying to customise and personalise are mouse buttons. [As seen from my previous question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117761/58313), I use SteerMouse to successfully configure the buttons on my Logitech M545 mouse.

However, there are two buttons, the side buttons, that cannot be detected by SteerMouse. After testing, I find that **these two buttons, when pressed, actually correspond to keyboard operations**. That is why SteerMouse is not able to configure them two.

Therefore, my question is equivalent to configuring two buttons of an external keyboard. How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step might be to discover what key codes they are putting out. [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) will do this for you.

Then you will find that [KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en) will allow you to map those keycodes to something useful.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried Key Codes, and find out that one button actually corresponds to a combination, command+d. Can KepRemap4Macbook deal with the combination key case?

Comment: Also, command+d is sometimes useful, e.g. adding a page into favourite in Safari. So overriding it may not be a good idea, I think.